# Android API Google Drive “connection failed”

Tags: android

I try to work with the API Google Drive on Android
However, I have this error that I can not solve .

**GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}**

public class GoogleDriveBackup implements Backup, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    @Nullable
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

```
@Nullable
private WeakReference<Activity> activityRef;


@Override
public void init(@NonNull final Activity activity) {
    this.activityRef = new WeakReference<>(activity);

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                    // Do nothing

                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}

@Override
public GoogleApiClient getClient() {
    return googleApiClient;
}

@Override
public void start() {
    if (googleApiClient != null) {
        googleApiClient.connect();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You should call init before start");
    }
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    if (googleApiClient != null) {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You should call init before start");
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull final ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i("error", "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());

    if (result.hasResolution() && activityRef != null && activityRef.get() != null) {
        Activity a = activityRef.get();
        // show the localized error dialog.
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(a, 1);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            FirebaseCrash.log("Drive connection failed");
            FirebaseCrash.report(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(a, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("error", "cannot resolve connection issue");
    }
}
```

}

Please Help

Comment: Have you solved it? Is it perhaps related to the deprecation: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/Drive ?